# How to recover python source code files in a readable format from an .exe file?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I used pyinstxtractor.py on my exe successfully, inside it there is a "File" with no extension that has the same name as the .exe and I can see some of my source code inside it but it's garbled up with symbols I don't recognize, I can only see snippets of my source.

pyinstaller was used with the --onefile argument :(

Is there any way I can recover my .py files in their original state or even somewhat close to it? I've read the comments will be gone, that is okay. I know there is uncompyle6, but there are hundreds of .pyc files in here I don't recognize... is there any way to home in on where pyinstaller put my actual .py files?

Comment: There's no reason to expect the `.py` file will be in there at all; `.pyc` is all you need to run, and it's faster to load them rather than parsing the `.py` files on each launch.

Comment: Understood, but my source code from the .py files I originally had is in one of these .pyc files right? and I can get that code back somehow?

Comment: `.pyc` files do not contain the original `.py` file. They're the compiled bytecode produced from the `.py`; it won't have comments, it strips whitespace, etc. The bytecode has more information than typical compiled code (since Python is pretty string oriented), but it can't be reversed to the exact original code.

Comment: That would also be fine. Can I use decompyle6 to extract code from a .pyc that I can use to rebuild my project? There's a ton of .pyc files is there any way to tell which one(s) contain my code?